# Can someone explain what is going on in this code? (arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, ternary-operator

I've tried to understand this one, but no chance. How it works?

```
    #include <stdio.h>  

    int tavuk(int i) 
    {     
        return (i%3 != 0 ? i + tavuk(--i) : i); 
    }  

    void main(void) 
    {     
        int *p, array_a[]={5,2,4,7,3};     
        p = array_a;     
        printf("%d", tavuk(array_a[*(++p)])); 
    }
```

Comment: Which part of that code do you not understand? All of it?

Comment: This looks like student test. To check whether students understand the flow.

Comment: If what you don't understand is recursion then check this: http://www.danzig.us/cpp/recursion.html

Comment: is it printing the number 7? (I just read the code..)

Comment: @tp1 it's 6 but how you got the 7, I can't even understand how it works.

Comment: *(++p) gives you 2. array_a[2] gives you 4. tavuk(4) gives you 4+tavuk(3) which gives you 4+3 = 7. The only reason why it should give 6 would be if --i is evaluated before i+tavuk(--i) evaluates the first i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach a debugger to the program, place some breakpoints and step through it one line at a time, so you can watch the code do its magic. Maybe adding additional parenthesis and spaces around illegible expressions could help you as well.

I wrote a step by step explanation of what happens below (read it at your own risk):

- `p` points to the first element in `array_a[]` after `p = array_a;`
- then `++p` is executed and `p` points to the second element in `array_a` (and its address is returned to the dereference operator `*`)
- `*` returns the value (2) of the second field in the array (since `++p` returned the address of `array_a[1]`)
- now `array_a[2]` is retrieved and its value (4) is passed into `tavuk(...)`
- inside `tavuk(...)` `(4%3 != 0)` evaluates to true
- `--i` is executed (now `i = 3`)
- `tavuk(...)` is called with 3, inside it `(3%3 != 0)` evaluates to false and 3 is returned
- the decremented `i` (3) is added to the return value of the second `tavuk(...)` call (also 3) and 6 is returned
- 6 is printed to stdout

Comment: That was the thing that I'm searching for, a big thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Initially p points to the beginning of the array array_p.
The statement array_a[*(++p)] can be broken down as follows:

- ++p ==> increment point to next memory address, in this case address of array_p[1]
- *(++p) ==> integer value at this address, in this case 2 or array_p[1]

Therefore, you pass integer value of 2 to the tavuk method.
Upon returning from the method, you would get a value of 5.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't really understand the part that how it really works. I mean if you say printf("bla bla"); it brings bla bla to your screen that's how it works or if you do i++ to 5 it will bring you a 4, but this one compiles 6. But how? If you've got some free time can you explain me step by step to reach that 6. Thanks again.